# Summernote showing image in editor only if it's uploaded in the same folder

Tags: javascript, summernote

I've examined the many Summernote q&a's about Summernote's onImageUpload topic, with no luck; so I'm trying a new answer here.

**Quick recap: I can make Summernote show the uploaded image in the textarea *only if* the image is uploaded in the same folder as index.php (i.e. the page with the form and the ajax request).**

N.B. jQuery is 3.3.1.min; Bootstrap is 4.1.3; Summernote is 0.8.9; they are all included via CDN in the given order in the HEAD section of HTML.

**My HTML/JS (index.php)**:

```
<form name="myEditor" id="myEditor" method="post" action="show.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea id="summernote" name="summernote"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">                 
    $(function() {  

        $('#summernote').summernote({
            placeholder: 'Write something...',
            lang: 'it-IT',
            height: 500,
            minHeight: null,
            maxHeight: null,
            focus: true,
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload: function(files) {
                    editor = $(this);
                    doTheUpload(files[0], editor);
                }
            }
        });

        function doTheUpload(uploadedImage, myEditor) {
            var myForm = new FormData();
            myForm.append("imageField", uploadedImage);
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: myForm,
                type: "post",
                success: function(imageUrl) {
                    var image = $('<img>').attr('src', imageUrl);
                    $(myEditor).summernote("insertNode", image[0]);
                },
                error: function(myForm) {
                    console.log(myForm);
                }
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

**MY PHP (upload.php)**:

```
$path = "";
$return_value = "";
$path = 'img/';

if ($_FILES['imageField']['name']) {

    if (!$_FILES['imageField']['error']) {

        $filename = $_FILES['imageField']['name'];
        $temp_location = $_FILES['imageField']['tmp_name'];         
        $final_destination = $path . $filename;

        if (!move_uploaded_file($temp_location, $final_destination)) {
            $return_value = $path . 'badimage.png';
        } else {
            $return_value = $final_destination;
        }

    } else {

        $return_value = "You triggered this error: " . $_FILES['imageField']['error'];

    }

}

echo $return_value;
```

**So what?**

So, the image file appears to be correctly uploaded on the server, in whatever 'path' I give to `$path`; in the example it's `$path = 'img/'`, but it can be anything else and it works regardless.
After all it's a simple `move_uploaded_file` PHP function at work here, I say to myself. Besides, the '`img/`' folder has the same permissions than the base.

The issue clicks when the ball passes back to `index.php`.

If the image was uploaded in the same folder as `index.php`, as to say `$path = ''`, everything's fine; the image is shown in the editor.

But if `$path` is anything different than `''` (just like the example above where it's `'img/'`), then the image is not shown in the editor and I get a nice 404.
As I said before, the file is actually uploaded in the correct folder on the server, I can even move it in another folder or download it back and edit it... I mean... ***it's there*** (isn't it?).

But not for the browser, and not for Summernote. However I point the browser to the image, provided it's in a subfolder, I get a 404.

With all the trials I've done so far, I only found a hint which I can see in Chrome's "Inspect -> Network": if the image is in the same folder as `index.php`, the server... serves me a png (or whatever other image type I upload); while if there's a path in the url before the filename, the file is served as text/html.

But I've other `move_uploades_files`'s elsewhere, where Summernote is not involved, and they work like charm...

I don't know guys, I'm in a dead end here...
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you post a complete example with all the scripts included that can be run to reproduce the issue? From the examples on github (https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/72), I see that php should return image URL and `success` handler in ajax request should do `success: function(url) { editor.insertImage(myEditor, url); }`.

Comment: I've posted an answer below, check the link to the docker-based setup, it works. Re-reading your question, I think the problem is actually this: `if the image is in the same folder as index.php, the server... serves me a png (or whatever other image type I upload); while if there's a path in the url before the filename, the file is served as text/html` - so it is probably something with php or web server settings. Would be good if you provided a docker-based broken setup similar to what I have in my answer, that way it would be possible to check and say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your example actually works for me (with small modifications to make the code acutally runnable via `php -S ...`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Summernote upload test</title>
    <!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- include summernote css/js -->
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myEditor" id="myEditor" method="post" action="show.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea id="summernote" name="summernote"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $('#summernote').summernote({
            placeholder: 'Write something...',
            lang: 'it-IT',
            height: 500,
            minHeight: null,
            maxHeight: null,
            focus: true,
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload: function(files) {
                    editor = $(this);
                    doTheUpload(files[0], editor);
                }
            }
        });

        function doTheUpload(uploadedImage, myEditor) {
            var myForm = new FormData();
            myForm.append("imageField", uploadedImage);
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: myForm,
                type: "post",
                success: function(imageUrl) {
                    var image = $('<img>').attr('src', imageUrl);
                    $(myEditor).summernote("insertNode", image[0]);
                },
                error: function(myForm) {
                    console.log(myForm);
                }
            });
        }

    });
</script>
</body>
```

And `upload.php`:

```
<?php
$path = "";
$return_value = "";
$path = 'img/';

if (!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path);
}

if ($_FILES['imageField']['name']) {

    if (!$_FILES['imageField']['error']) {

        $filename = $_FILES['imageField']['name'];
        $temp_location = $_FILES['imageField']['tmp_name'];
        $final_destination = $path . $filename;

        if (!move_uploaded_file($temp_location, $final_destination)) {
            $return_value = $path . 'badimage.png';
        } else {
            $return_value = $final_destination;
        }

    } else {

        $return_value = "You triggered this error: " . $_FILES['imageField']['error'];

    }

}

echo $return_value;
?>
```

The only change I've made (besides adding script imports to `index.php` file and php tags to `upload.php`) is "mkdir($path)".

See also [the full code example based on docker](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/tree/master/php-summernote).

And there might be various reasons why you are getting the issue, for example, the "img/" folder does not exist or it is not writable.

To debug the issue, open browser developer tools (F12 in chrome and firefox) and check the output of the network request to "upload.php".

Comment: Hey Boris, thanks for your time. To be completely sure I took your example from github and run that instead of mine; alas, the result is the same: status 404, not found.
Btw the img folder was already existant and writable even without mkdir; in fact upload.php correctly uploads the image into it, as it's always done so far.
The response for upload.php is status 200, ok.

Comment: @Marks did you run my example with docker? There is a makefile and you can do "make start" or take the docker command from there.

Comment: Sorry Boris, my knowledge of docker (and of github, btw) is equal to 0 :-/
I really do think that there's something here that eludes my brain... especially if you say that it works for you. I just need to figure how what and where it is.

Comment: @Marks that is exactly what I am trying to help with, my experiment has shown that your code works when I run it with php dev server (actually you can also try something like "php -S localhost:8000"). So it looks like the problem is not with summernote, but with your webserver / php setup.

Comment: @Marks by the way, what you see if you open the image by URL directly? For example, if you upload the banner.png and then open "http://localhost:8080/img/banner.png" (assuming you have the app on localhost:8080), do you see the image?

Comment: I'm not working locally, basically because the php that executes move_uploaded_files is nearly identical to others that I have in my cms (which is custom) and I didn't even think there would have been issues of any kind since those other scripts have always worked.
The main difference is that -this- PHP is called by ajax, where the others are not.
Moreover, the website for which I'm working is on a shared hosting, I don't have access to the webserver configuration; I just can choose the PHP version.
But, as I said, other nearly identical scripts do work.

Comment: Anyway if I point the browser to the file, it returns the infamous 404. Even if I can manage it with the ftp client, meaning the file appears to be there, but for some reason it's "invisible" by the "public".
I am starting a test on Xampp right now, let's see if anything pops out!

Comment: Ok, locally works, remotely doesn't. I mean, the very same scripts, files copied and pasted. That should be the final proof that the issue resides within the hosting provider server configuration's boundaries, I guess. I should talk to them.
@Boris I wish to thank you for your efforts and your patience!